# Quantum mechanics: orbitals with opposite signs in the magnetic quantum number

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, orbitals

In quantum mechanics, the orbitals, psi (n, l, m) and psi (n, l, -m) have opposite signs in the magnetic quantum number but they have the same absolute value.

(i) Are the probability density distributions in these orbitals always identical? That is, when we plot the probability density for each of the orbitals in three dimensional space, will the two plots look the same?

(ii) If an orbital can accommodate two electrons, it means that these two orbitals, psi (n, l, m) and psi (n, l, -m), can accommodate four electrons. However, if the answer to the last question is yes, we are talking about the same physical space for the two orbitals. Does that means four electrons are occupying the same physical space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are considering the difference between two states:

\begin{align}
|2,1,+1\rangle \text{ and } |2,1,-1\rangle
\end{align}

To answer your questions directly:

(i) The probability distribution for these two states are in fact identical. That is to say, the probability of finding the electron in a specific position $(x,y,z)$ with respect to the atomic nucleus is the same regardless of which state the atom is in.

However, this does *NOT* mean the two states are the same. You must recall that quantum states have an associated phase. If we are considering the wavefunction then we must recall that the wavefunction is a complex number at every point in space. For these two states it turns out that the *magnitude* of the two wavefunctions are the same but the *phase* of the two wavefunctions differ. For example, the complex numbers $3i+4$ and $5i$ both have magnitudes of $5$ but they are clearly different complex numbers.

For the two electron wavefunctions I'll describe and show their wavefunctions including phase information.
In one case the phase wraps clockwise around the $z$ axis while in the other case it wrap counter-clockwise around the $z$ axis. See the figure below.

[image]

Recall that the wavefunction is a complex valued function in 3D space. In this image we have identified a 2D contour surface for which the wavefunction has a particular constant magnitude. The magnitude has been chosen so that the probability of finding the electron inside the surface is 45%. The surface has been colored (on a rainbow scale) according to the phase of the wavefunction on the contour surface. As I described you can see the phase wrapping clockwise in one case and counter-clockwise in the the other case (look at the colors going from red, through yellow and green to blue, I believe red is a phase of $0$ and blue is a phase of $\pi$)

In fact, one can notice that [probability current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current) is related to the gradient of the phase of the wavefunction. In this sense the curling of the phase around the $z$-axis can be thought of a the probability current flowing around the axis, or equivalently, one could calculate the local electron velocity and see that this looks like the electron flowing in a circle around the nucleus.

This is then a truly beautiful picture because we know that the states we have written down are states with non-zero angular momentum. That is, one state should have one unit of angular momentum along the $+z$ direction and the other should have angular momentum in the $-z$ direction. This is now very nicely visualized by the picture of the electron flowing either clockwise or counter-clockwise according to whichever phase gradient it's wavefunction exhibits.

(ii) Regarding Pauli exclusion principle and this question. I hope I have convinced you above that while the probability distributions (the magnitudes of the wavefunctions) are the same, the states themselves are still different because of the phase information. From this we can conclude that it is ok for electrons to occupy the same physical space so long as their phases are different. Or said differently, it is ok for the electrons to occupy the same space so long as their momenta are different.

And I will add a note here regarding visualization of atomic orbitals. Unfortunately it is rare that these visualizations of the *complex* atomic orbitals are shown. That is sad because I think they are very pretty pictures and they can provide nice physical intuition. What is often shown are visualizations of the *real* orbitals which are the real and imaginary parts of the complex orbitals. These have the advantage that you only need to think about if the phase is positive or negative. These are helpful for chemists thinking about chemistry. However, these depictions are a bit confusing to physicists learning quantum mechanics because they actually depict states in which the electron is in a superposition of two different angular momentum states. That is:

\begin{align}
\psi_{real} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_{2,1,+1} + \psi_{2,1,-1})\\
\psi_{imag} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}i}(\psi_{2,1,+1} - \psi_{2,1,-1})\\
\end{align}

See the discussion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Complex_orbitals)

Comment: Your first line says $|2,1,-2\rangle$ when I believe you meant -1. It isn't enough characters for me to edit in directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. In that case, does that mean four electrons are occupying the same physical space? I think the answer is yes. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes all four occupy the same physical space. But I point out again that they have different momenta. I also point out that to some degree even electrons in s and p orbitals “occupy the same physical space” to some degree..

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been so helpful. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If my response answers your question then please upvote it and mark it as answered!